# Where is f complex differentiable

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-analysis

Let $f(z):=2|z|^2-\overline{z}^2$ where $z\in \mathbb{C}$

At what points is f complex differentiable?

I can assume $\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\overline{h}}{h}$ does not exist.

I have $$\lim_{h\to0} [2z\frac{\overline{h}}{h} + 2\overline{z}+2\overline{h}-2\overline{z}\frac{\overline{h}}{h}-\frac{\overline{h}^2}{h}]$$

So I get f is complex differentiable at 0.

But when I use Cauchy - Riemann equations.

$F(x,y)=(x^2+3y^2,2xy)$
$$DF(x,y)= 
\begin{vmatrix}
2x&6y\\
2y&2x\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
I get y=0 so is differentiable at all real numbers? Which one is right?

(b) Is f holomorphic anywhere? Do I use the CR equations to answer this?

Comment: What is your argument from the limit to conclude that $f$ is complex differentiable only at $0$? Maybe you should combine two terms into $2(z-\bar z)\bar h/h$?

Answer (score 1):

In your first computation, you want to know when that limit exists as $h\to 0$. It certainly exists when $z=0$, but, in fact, it exists whenever $z-\bar z = 0$, i.e., on the real axis.

So far as your second is concerned, what is your textbook's definition of holomorphic? Does it require complex differentiability on a neighborhood?

Comment: Ok thanks. And holomorphicity requires f to be complex differentiable on an open set.

Comment: Well, then, you know the answer to the second question. :)

Comment: Nowhere? Because the line y=0 doesn't contain an open set?

Comment: Right you are!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You're very welcome. I know you're new here, so I'll let you know that once you're satisfied, you should accept the answer, so that the question does not continue to appear as unanswered.